# ''pull the plug on something''

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

It was on a book cover:

> The wise and hilarious story of a family who discovered that having
>   fewer tools to communicate with actually led them to communicate more.
>
> When Susan Maushart first announced her intention to **pull the plug
>   on her family's entire collection of electronic gadgets for six
>   months**, her three kids didn’t react at all. Says Maushart, "Looking
>   back, I can understand why. They didn't hear me."

what does ''pull the plug on sth" mean?

Comment: Did you look it up in a dictionary? What did you find?  "[Pull the plug](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pull-the-plug)" can have a figurative meaning but here it can also be taken in the literal sense (look at [the cover](http://images.penguinrandomhouse.com/cover/9781585428557) of the book) to understand plug, and [pull](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pull) is rather straightforward once you've got "plug".

Comment: @Laure The answer of Robusto is correct. but I have another question, in literal meaning can we say pull the plug ''of'' something? or just we can say pull the plug ''on''?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a metaphor meaning to stop using or doing something, to cancel it. It comes from the literal act of pulling the power plug from an electronic device.

In your example, it means that Ms. Maushart intended to make her family go for six months with no use of electronic gadgets.

Comment: In the literal act, ''pull on'' in ''pull the plug on'' is a phrasal verb or ''on'' is for the plug? I mean we can say plug on my CD player or plug of my CD player?

Comment: In the literal act you could say either "of" or "on" ... but the latter is more figurative and the former more literal. Use of "on" is standard in the metaphor.